# object does not support indexing when overriding __getitem__

Tags: python

The Solution class inherits from object class, TypeError occurs: 'Solution' object does not support indexing? But if Solution class does not inherit from object, the code works find. My question is why Solution class does not support indexing when it inherits from object, even though it override **getitem** method.

```
class Solution(object):
    def findMin(self, nums):
        self.__getitem__ = lambda i: nums[i] <= nums[-1]
        return nums[bisect.bisect(self, False, 0, len(nums))]
```

Comment: So, I'm assuming you are on Python 2?

Comment: This seems like a really convoluted way to implement that functionality.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right, I am using python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you inherit from `object`, you create a new-style class rather than an old style class.  For new-style classes, `__getitem__` is looked up on the *class*, not on the *instance* of the class.  Even though you've added a `__getitem__` method to a class *instance* (`self`), you haven't added that method to the class and therefore the lookup fails (for new style classes).

For old style classes, presumably the lookup still happens on the instance which is why the code works when you don't inherit from `object`.  Careful though -- In python3.x, **all classes are new style whether you inherit from `object` explicitly or not**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like something this:

```
import bisect

class Solution(object):
    __getitem__ = lambda self, i: self.nums[i] <= self.nums[-1]

    def findMin(self, nums):
        self.nums = nums
        return nums[bisect.bisect(self, False, 0, len(nums))]

sol = Solution()
sol.findMin([42, 1, 13])
```

`__getitem__` needs to be defined at the class, not instance, level in new-style classes (those whose base-class is `object` in Python 2, and all classes in Python 3—whether explicitly specified or not).